# How can I set a custom name for the EF core migration history table and have it used when generating migration scripts?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project which uses EF Core, and migrations have already been run using the default migration history table (`dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory`). I want to store all migrations in a table with a different name and schema.

In `ConfigureServices` (within `Startup.cs`) I have the following code ([as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table#schema-and-table-name)):

```cs
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(
            connectionString,
            x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__MigrationHistory", "MySchema"));
    });
```

I have manually created the `MySchema.__MigrationHistory` table, copied over all the data from `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory`, and dropped `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory`.

I was expecting this to mean that all future migrations would go into `MySchema.__MigrationHistory` but when I added a blank migration as a test and ran `script-migration -from previousMigrationName` (from the Visual Studio package manager console) the SQL it gave me adds the history record to `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory`.

What else do I need to do in order to get EF Core to use `MySchema.__MigrationHistory` for all new migrations?

Comment: If you run script migration can you check what do you get: Script-Migration -From previousMigrationName  -To BlankMigration

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought to try that. Unfortunately it gives the same result - it inserts into `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory` rather than `MySchema.__MigrationHistory`.

Comment: If you create blank database and try to just update it with all migrations will it work then? Or if you create (just for test) only one Initial migration for blank database?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found what the issue was and posted an answer in the hope it benefits someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason for this problem was that I hadn't understood how EF Core is configured to run migrations when the `DbContext` is in a different assembly from the ASP.NET Core app.

The ASP.NET Core app has a `Startup.cs` which I'd modified, but I wasn't aware that the assembly containing the `DbContext` contained an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. In this class there is another call to the `UseSqlServer` method, and I needed to add the options there too. This is what is actually being used for migrations, as they don't go through the ASP.NET Core app.